# Android VideoView, need to switch between videos quickly

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I'm developing a new app and am using VideoView to display mpeg clips.

I need to switch between videos very quickly, however, loading a new clip to a VideoView seems to take about half a second of black screen.

The transition must be seamless, how would you go about solving this kind of problem?

Comment: probably no way to do that unless you write your own video decoder

Comment: is it possible to have a VideoView hidden behind the one playing and to hide the active one once it's done?

Comment: Try it. I don't know but it might work that way.

Comment: Can you post the code how you switch to next video?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved with a still-image (ImageView) transition:

- build a FrameLayout with an ImageView over the VideoView
- the ImageView shows the first frame of the video
- initially the ImageView is visible
- start the video, wait for an arbitrary time (e.g. 2-300ms)
- hide the ImageView

to switch two videos:
- show the image
- switch the video
- hide the image

a bit hackish but worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but I used `mediaplayer`, my code is:

Here I use a button to trigger the switch action, before switching, I have already loaded the video and prepare for switching. When you need to do so, you just need to stop and release the old `mediaplayer` and starting the new one.The key point for seamless switching is the `sleep()`, when the process is sleeping, actually the video is still going on, but give the system some time to prepare for the next one.

```
    switch_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_switch);
    switch_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button switch_button = (Button) v;
            VideoPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                VideoPlayer2.setDataSource("rtsp://" + hostIP + ":1935/vod/Timer.mp4");
                VideoPlayer2.prepare();
                VideoPlayer2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            VideoPlayer.release();
            VideoPlayer2.setDisplay(vidHolder);
            VideoPlayer2.start();
        }
    });
```